Video stream very slow in Ubuntu server
i have this code that connect to rtsp camera:
from flask import Flask, Response
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

RTSP_URL = "rtsp://admin:xxxxxxx@x.x.x.x:554/onvif1"

def generate_frames():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(RTSP_URL)
    frame_skip = 2  # Skip every 2 frames
    while True:
        for _ in range(frame_skip):
            cap.read()  # Skip frames
        success, frame = cap.read()
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            # Resize frame to lower resolution
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (320, 240))  # Reduce to 320x240 resolution
            # Encode frame to JPEG format with lower quality
            encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 30]  # Set JPEG quality to 30
            _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            # Yield frame in MJPEG format
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(generate_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

It work fine in my local pc even the camera and pc are in different network(im using ubuntu desktop) but i purchased a ubuntu server and used the same exact code and i opened the flask throguh :http://x.x.x.x:5000/video_feed and thats the ip of the ubuntu server and its very very slow even i did the same exact installation of the librareis and the harware of the server is much stronger than my ubuntu desktop,i lowered resolution and it wokred a little bit better but its still very very slow. The ubuntu server have a very better connection than my ubuntu deskotp and as i told you it have rtx 4090 24gb and 100 gb ram so its not a deal for a video stream from an rtsp camera
